# Reason for leaving current job on application form when applying for previous job?

Tags: recruitment, applications, employment

I am applying for my previous job with the same company that I still work for in my current position.

I don't like my current job in the organisation and I want to go back to what I enjoyed doing before my current position which is why I am reapplying to my old job. I would like to know how to word or phrase this better on the job application form which asks about my current job for which I am leaving, how do I say I would like to return to the position more formally or better worded on a job application?:

**Reason for leaving (if applicable) :**
........................................................

Thanks all :)

Comment: Hi Joe,  thanks for your reply. On the job application, on my job history I have listed my current position and I have filled out the start date but should I fill out the end date in my current position on the job application, as I know my last day since I have given my notice in for my current position? or should I leave it bank?

Answer (score 3):

The application form is a boilerplate document that generally assumes you are leaving some other company to go there, and allows them to do a little digging on what, if any issues, there might have been.  They gather preliminary information on someone who is, previously, unknown to them.

That's not the case here, since you're not actually "leaving" anything for the new position.  You're staying with the company, and they don't have to dig about anything because your experiences with the company you are staying with are well-known to them.  Their standard process is to have an application filled out, so they make you do it to, but how they use it (if at all), will be very different.

So, in this case, it's a formality.  Leave it simple - "internal position change for more desired position."  Bam.  Done, and you don't burn any bridges or ruffle any feathers.  OR - since it says "if applicable" - you could also fill in "N/A (not applicable) - internal transfer."  Anything bland, generic and not especially informative will do.  They won't care.  They ***will*** care if you say "my current position stinks, I never should have left the previous one."

In the interview they might ask why you want to go back to a position or area you had before.  Just state that you really, really enjoyed your time at that position and miss the work, as much as you value the experiences gained in your current one.

Answer (score 1):

The only explanation for leaving a job which I would give is that the job does not enable me to have the professional development which I like.

During an interview somebody could ask for specifics, but on a form i would only write that.

Comment: In my opinion that is already too personal. I might enter something if for example I need a new job because my significant other found one that we would have to move for and now I am looking for a job at that location. That is a "no bad feelings, neutral" answer I could think of. Otherwise... it's not applicable (because it's my business).

Answer (score 1):

I feel I am a stronger candidate for the [prior] position, and I am better able to help the company achieve it's goals in [prior] position.

...or just leave it blank

keep in mind, your current manager may read the comment you write

Answer (score 1):

**Reason for Leaving**

*The skills and experience gained my current position will compliment and augment my existing skills in the position to which I am applying.  This will enable me to maximize my productivity and value to the organization in that position.*

Answer (score 0):

You are applying for an internal job with the same company. The job app is written from the generic point of view.  I would simply answer this with "internal transfer" - it's not empty and it passes the smell test.